# How can I have bigger circles in a <ul> link

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am using `<ul>`'s and I would like to have the circles (just the circles or disks) the start off each `<li>` appear bigger. Is there an easy way to do this with CSS?

Answer (score 7):

How `disc`, `circle` and other list style types are rendered is up to the browser to decide, and is fixed on a browser-by-browser basis. Even different versions of IE draw them at different sizes.

You can't control this without altering the markup (see [Marty Wallace's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120225/how-can-i-have-bigger-circles-in-a-ul-link/6120329#6120329)) unless you make your own circle images to use with `list-style-image` instead. (Still provide `list-style-type` as a *fallback* for when images can't load, etc.)

Answer (score 7):

You could just put a `<span>` with a smaller font size around the content of the `<li>`.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><span>list item</span></li>
    <li><span>list item</span></li>
    <li><span>list item</span></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul
{
    font-size: 20px;
}

li > span
{
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Totally brought on via an epiphany :P

Comment: Also, you're a Flash game dev? Nice - I've been meaning to give that a shot myself. I haven't used Flash for anything but the occasional doodle in a long time.

Comment: Flash games are definitely a passion and hobby but unfortunately they don't come up where I work.. I mostly do banner ads and on seldom occasions a nifty Flash application of some type.

Answer (score 0):

as answered by @BoltClock, you should use custom images like shown below. Assume that you have ball.gif in the current directory (which can be bigger in your case).

```
<UL STYLE="list-style-image: url(ball.gif)">
<LI>Bullet 1</LI> 
<LI>Bullet 2</LI>
</UL>
```